# How to check that a file is local

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm developping an app for Windows 8.1 and I want to warn the user if he uses a file that is not on the device.

How can I check if a file, selected by the user with the FilePicker, is located on the current device or not (maybe on a network share, on a NAS, on a USD disk...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```cs
var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
var provider = file.Provider;

if (provider.Id != "computer")
{
    // TODO: Warn the user here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I suspected something like that. I saw the Id property, but it's a string (and not an enum) and I couldn't find any documentation or blog post about the different possible values.